# How to fetch data from an Array

Tags: php, arrays, oop, foreach

Hi i have written a class to get data from database, and in view i am creating an instance of that class to get the data.

Everything seems working fine, when i use `print_r($emp_data)` in my view. It returns data in the following format,

```
Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [emp_id] => 1 
        [1] => Aftab 
        [first_name] => Aftab 
        [2] => Kirmani 
        [last_name] => Kirmani 
        [3] => Male 
        [gender] => Male 
        [4] => 1 
        [added_by] => 1 
       )
```

but when i use `foreach` loop it gives me an error message.

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'emp_id' in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\emp_management\Views\view_all_employees.php on line
>   11

Following is the code i have written.

**`Class Method`**

```
public function get_employees(){
    $query= "select * from employees";
    $query_run= mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0){
        $data= mysqli_fetch_array($query_run);
        return $data;           
    }
}
```

**`View`**

```
<?php 

include 'header.php';

$employees= new Employees();

$emp_data= $employees->get_employees();

foreach($emp_data as $data){

    echo $data['emp_id'];

}
?>
```

Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong here. I think `array` is not returning the data in correct format.

Thanks

Comment: Is it correct your array value for `$emp_data` ?

Comment: Yes it is, I am filling this array from my class..but its filling this in this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array` returns a single row. Your loop (after you've called your 'fetch' function) is assuming you have retrieved all employees. Correct your class function like:

```
public function get_employees(){
    $query = "select * from employees";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0){
        $data = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run) {
            $data[] = $row; //this puts all your rows in an array
        }
        return $data;           
    }
}
```

You can leave your `View` loop as is. It should work as expected.